# Implementing BFS algorithm with a max depth and that prints all shortest paths

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

This is the BFS algorithm I came up with to print all the shortest paths from root node to any other node in the graph:

```
d = deque()
d.append(root)
level = 0
while len(d) >= 0 and level <= max_depth:
    u = d.popleft()
    print(adjacency_list[u])
    for v in adjacency_list[u]:
        if visited[v] == 'N':
            if nodes2distances[u] + 1 <= nodes2distances[v]:
                nodes2distances[v] = nodes2distances[u] + 1
                node2parents[v].append(u)
                d.extend(v)
    level += 1
    visited[u] = 'Y'
```

The above code works fine when I don't specify the max level condition, however, the output varies every time I run this algorithm with a restriction on level.

1) Could you explain how i could implement this algorithm with level restriction(i.e specifying the maximum level)?

2) Also, could you please let me know if the approach I have taken to solve the problem can be better?

Edit :
Ok!!Sorry, I didn't do it before!! 
Say I have the following edges in a unweighted graph:

**('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'),('D', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'F'), ('G', 'F')**

After implementing my code without the restriction of depth, I get the following output when i call the algorithm for node **'B'**,

```
[('A', ['B']), ('C', ['B']), ('D', ['B']), ('E', ['D']), ('F', ['D']), ('G', ['D'])]
```

However, when I call the same function with a level restriction of 2, i.e., `myFunction(graph,'E',2)`, I get the following output:

```
[('A', ['B']), ('C', ['B']), ('D', ['B'])]
```

whereas, the expected output is

```
[('A', ['B']), ('C', ['B']), ('D', ['B']),('E',['D']),('F', ['D']),('G',['D'])]
```

Comment: Please provide examples (sample inputs, expected output, actual output)

Comment: Please explain what this output represents. How is this all shortest paths?

Comment: Hello Sarid!Since this is an unweighted graph, the shortest path is the number of levels from the root to the node. In the above example, i am just printing the parents, so it looks confusing. I have been on stack overflow for some time now, but i had never posted questions before(i am learning now), so apologies for the way i have framed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing level at the wrong place. Each node's level is equal to its parent level plus 1. You should not increment level globally in the `while` loop. Instead you should store the level of each node you put in the queue. Something like this:

```
d = deque()
          #node,level
d.append( (root,0   ) )
while len(d) >= 0:
    front = d.popleft()
    u = front[0]
    level = front[1]
    if level >= max_depth:
        break
    print(adjacency_list[u])
    for v in adjacency_list[u]:
        if visited[v] == 'N':
            if nodes2distances[u] + 1 <= nodes2distances[v]:
                nodes2distances[v] = nodes2distances[u] + 1
                node2parents[v].append(u)
                d.append( (v,level+1) )
    visited[u] = 'Y'
```

Comment: Hey!!Thanks for your reply!!I understood what you are trying to do here. While executing the above program, "d.extend(v,level+1)" gives me an error  when we reach "level = front[0]". I changed it to "d.append(v,level+1)". It worked for max_depth=2. But it failed for max_depth = 5, so i had to change the condition in while loop to 'len(d)>0'. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Nik.Birur I hope you have gotten the idea ;)

Comment: yes!!Thank you so much!!Before you explained, i was so confused, but only after i looked at your solution, i feel it's so easy!!Lol!!Thanks again for the help!!You are the best!!

Comment: Sir, what do you think is the complexity of the above algorithm? I feel its still O(V+E), but however, since we are limiting the depth and also, since we are printing all the shortest paths, does the complexity change??

Comment: You can say that it *O(V+E)* because these restriction don't necessarily improve the worst case.

Comment: But how is this possible, if the max_depth is lesser than the last level in the tree, won't the worst case decrease then?? I am just confused!!should it be O(V+E)*log(k) where k is the max depth??

Comment: BFS complexity is in *O(V+E)* even if you think by cutting of from some depth the complexity will decrease it won't become O(V+E)*log(k) because, O(V+E)*log(k) > O(V+E). But the complexity won't decrease. Just imagine a complete a graph. no matter what your max_depth is. You will visit all the nodes.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you are saying!!This makes a lot of sense!!Thank you!!